# Next.js catch all route with getStaticPaths and rewrites

Tags: next.js, catch-all

I have been banging my head on this specific set-up. I am trying to achieve a set-up with Next.js where I can rewrite different sets of category pages to a catch-all route. But it always leads to a 404. Does someone know why?

next.config.js

```
{
rewrites: async () => {
   return [{
      source: "/actual-route/:slug*",
      destination: "/collection/:slug*",
    },{
      source: "/another-route/:slug*",
      destination: "/collection/:slug*",
    }]
}
}
```

collection/[...slug].tsx

```
export async getStaticPaths() {
return {
      paths: [
        {
          params: {
            slug: ["actual-route"],
          },
        },
        {
          params: {
            slug: ["actual-route", "child"],
          },
        },
        {
          params: {
            slug: ["another-route"],
          },
        },
        {
          params: {
            slug: ["another-route", "another-child"],
          },
        },
      ],
      fallback: "blocking",
    };
}

export async getStaticProps({ params }) {
  return { props: {slug: params.slug}} // It doesn't get to here
}
```

Comment: have found a solution?